# how can I check two date-time are equal in django templates

Tags: python, django

I am trying to check if some date-time equal with date-time that come from db before that I check one time is larger or smaller from another.

Here is the code:

```
{% for order in orders %}
    {% if order.hour_id.open == dic and order.status == 'Reserved' %}
        <div class="col late pastDate" data-dayid="22" data-timeid="38"
             data-price="65000" data-time="38"
             data-day="1" data-start="3" data-end="9" data-date="1398/2/14">reserved
        </div>

        {% set x = False %}
    {% elif order.hour_id.open == dic and order.status == 'Reserving' %}
        <div class="col late onrezerv" data-dayid="22" data-timeid="41"
             data-price="65000" data-time="41"
             data-day="1" data-start="39" data-end="45" data-date="1398/2/14">reserving
        {% set x = False %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Here is my dictionary
In my country first day of week day is saturday

```
day_of_week_miladi  = {
"shanbe": start_week_miladi - timedelta(days=2),
"yeshanbe": start_week_miladi + timedelta(days=1) - timedelta(days=2), "doshanbe": start_week_miladi + timedelta(days=2)- timedelta(days=2),
"seshanbe": start_week_miladi + timedelta(days=3)- timedelta(days=2), "charshanbe": start_week_miladi + timedelta(days=4)- timedelta(days=2),
"panjshanbe": start_week_miladi + timedelta(days=5)- timedelta(days=2), "jome": start_week_miladi + timedelta(days=6)- timedelta(days=2)
}
```

I want compare two special date time

```
one = datetime.strptime('00:30:00','%H:%M:%S').time()
    two = datetime.strptime('06:30:00','%H:%M:%S').time()
    three = datetime.strptime('08:00:00','%H:%M:%S').time()
    four = datetime.strptime('09:30:00','%H:%M:%S').time()
    five = datetime.strptime('11:00:00','%H:%M:%S').time()
    six = datetime.strptime('12:30:00','%H:%M:%S').time()
    ...
```

In this dictionary I trying to combine times and date:

```
datetime_three = {}
for id,dict in day_of_week_miladi.items():
    datetime_three[id] = datetime.combine(dict,three)
```

Comment: Where are you tying to compare these?

Comment: Can you share the relevant parts of your model definition?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem in the Html (template)

Comment: @Ami: but on what line(s) you do that here exactly?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem In {% elif order.hour_id.open == dic and order.status == 'Reserving' %}